# Different encodings used in in "print s" vs "print [s]"?

Tags: python, unicode

When I do the following in IPython notebook

```
s='½'
s
print s
print [s]
```

I see

```
'\xc2\xbd'
½
['\xc2\xbd']
```

1. What's going on here?
2. How do I print a list of Unicode strings? (ie I want to see ['½'])

**Edit**
So from comments, looks like the difference is that "print s" uses `s.__str__` and "s", "print [s]" uses it's `s.__repr__`

Comment: Those are not Unicode strings, they're UTF-8-encoded bytestrings.

Comment: I see....so why does "print s" and "print [s]" treat the encoding differently?

Comment: Because that's how `list.__str__()` works.

Comment: @Yaroslav: `print s` uses the string's \_\_str\_\_, just `s` and `print [s]` use its \_\_repr\_\_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `repr` function to create a string containing a printable representation of your list, then decode your string with `string-escape` encoding which will returns a byte string of your string. Then by printing the byte string your terminal will encode it automatically by it's default encoding (usually UTF8) :

```
>>> print repr([s]).decode('string-escape')
['½']
```

But note that since in python 3.X we just have unicode, you don't need to use this trick :

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> s='½'
>>> print ([s])
['½']
```

For more info about python encodings read https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Comment: It's strange that that works. How does it know to decode escaped _UTF8_ strings?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich it's decoding bytes and printing bytes. The only thing decoding UTF-8 is the terminal.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich because `string_escape` will produce a string that is suitable as string literal in Python source code. And when you print the string your IDE or terminal perhaps will decode the string with it's default encoding (almost utf8)

Comment: I see. I thought the purpose of str.decode() was always to decode a byte string to a Unicode string, but now I read https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html and I see that there are several str to str codecs. Never knew.

Comment: [Don't use string-escape, fix the data format instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33484559/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Fixing the data format doesn't helps in this case (with regards to this point that you've solved the problem using `json` module and got my up-vote for this suggestion), also this solution will works even if the OP is not able to change the data format.

Comment: In addition to JSON format, a simple `", ".join([u'½'])` also can work (obviously, I meant the output data format i.e., I assume that OP has a list with strings and OP wants to get them in some human-readable format). There are at least two issues with your code: (1) it uses a bytestring instead of Unicode (2) `repr(obj).decode('string-escape')` is a hack at best (it is one step away from applying a regex to the result of `repr()` -- it should hint that you are moving in a wrong direction -- format the list directly instead e.g., `", ".join([u'½'])`).

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That's a good question, it will almost certainly break if you save that source file in another encoding than UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

`'\xc2\xbd'` is a printable representation of `bytes` on Python 2 where  non-printable ([`isprint()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isprint.html) is `0`) bytes are replaced with their hex codes e.g., `0xc2` byte is displayed as `\xc2` as in [Python bytestring literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

> What's going on here?

- `s` along in REPL is displayed using customizable [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) that calls [`repr(s)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) by default
- `print s` puts the bytes as is and it happens that your editor and the console use compatible encodings and therefore you haven't got a mojibake: the bytes are mapped to the same glyph: `½` (Unicode codepoint: [U+00bd VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF](http://codepoints.net/U+00bd))
- `print [s]` prints the list (it calls `str(your_list)`). `repr(item)` is called for each list item.

> How do I print a list of Unicode strings? (ie I want to see ['½'])

1. Use Unicode to work with text:

   (a) in particular, use Unicode string literals instead of bytestring literals: add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` or use `u''` prefix: `s = u'½'`

   (b) declare the character encoding of your *source code*, add at the top: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (note: it affects only the source code; it is unrelated to character encoding that may be used at runtime)

To print a list of Unicode strings as text, serialize it to string first:

```
print ", ".join([u'½'])
# -> ½
```

If you need to exchange the data with some other program; you could use JSON format:

```
import json

print json.dumps([u'½'])
# -> ["\u00bd"]
print json.dumps([u'½'], ensure_ascii=False)
# -> ["½"]
```

Don't use `string-escape`, fix your data format instead.